# Local HTML file in XML opening with Excel

Tags: python, html, excel, xml

I want to open Hyperlinks with Excel. I created a XML File with Python. The XML File contains local HTML-Path with References. In Excel I can open the Hyperlink and the Browser shows me the HTML but the Reference didn't function.

XML with HTML REF:

```
<link href="file:///C:/users/documents/test.html#nav_buttom"/>
```

When I try to open a website with reference, it works.
HTTP is no problem, but local files didn't function this way.